# Why seems add_rostest not to work?

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am migrating a packet to catkin. It contains a test.
The test runs successfully like this:

```
rostest my_navigation_test my_test_4_cob.test
```

but when i add

```
add_rostest(launch/my_test_4_cob.test)
```

to the equivalent CMakeLists.txt and call `catkin_make test` I get:

```
catkin_make test
Base path: /home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest
Source space: /home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/src
Build space: /home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/build
Devel space: /home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/devel
Install space: /home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make test -j8 -l8" in "/home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/build"
####
Running tests...
Test project /home/aub-ch/ros/hydro_mynavigationtest/build
    Start 1: _ctest_my_navigation_test_rostest_launch_my_test_4_cob.test
1/1 Test #1: _ctest_my_navigation_test_rostest_launch_my_test_4_cob.test ...***Failed    5.64 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   5.66 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - _ctest_my_navigation_test_rostest_launch_my_test_4_cob.test (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [test] Error 8
Invoking "make" failed
```

It is a bit hard to debug as it gives no feedback about what is really happening at all.
**Any ideas?**
Can you explain to me what the line '_ctest_my_navigation_test_rostest_launch_my_test_4_cob.test' means? Does it expect the launchfile to be called like this? (which it isn't)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174716/why-seems-add_rostest-not-to-work?/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
This might has been my fault, because i messed up my multiple workspaces. But I'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `catkin_make run_tests`, rather than just `test`.

See the [how-to run tests](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/run_tests.html) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
Thank you. This helps a lot as I can see the test output

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-06-24**:
You can also call `catkin_test_results` to get a summary of tests.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
Do you mind checking out my follow up question, too: http://answers.ros.org/question/174807/rostest-arguments-in-cmakelists/